# empty_data: Unable to reverse value for property path "countryOfOrigin": Expected a string or null

Tags: php, sonata, symfony-2.7

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 app that uses Sonata's admin bundle. I want to associate a Video with a Country, and I want to provide a default option if nothing is present. So I do this:

```
    $formMapper
        ->tab('General')
        ->with('Editable', ['class' => 'col-md-6'])
        ->add('title')
        ->add(
            'countryOfOrigin',
            'country_of_origin',
            [
                'empty_data' => $user->getOriginCountry()
            ]
        )
```

This works in that my record-creation screen gives me a nice form with my default value selected. But when I try to save my new record, I get this error:

> Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException Unable
>   to reverse value for property path "countryOfOrigin": Expected a
>   string or null.

**Any ideas on how to get around this error?** I feel like I'm 90% to my destination.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up punting on this for the moment by deciding not to have any default option. I would still be interested in hearing how others have solved this.